# Meteor get geolocation when app in background

Tags: cordova, meteor

I would like to create a very simple iphone app that reads the device's geolocation every minute and inserts it into a Mongo collection. I have already came across [this meteor geolocation background package](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/meteor-cordova-geolocation-background), but I don't understand how it works at all.

**Questions:**

1. What would the `GeolocationBG.config` look like in this case?
2. How exactly do I insert the data? I have no idea about GET and POST methods because I am not coming from the PHP world (started with Meteor).
3. Is there a way to run a piece of general Meteor code in background? That would totally help me out.

Your help highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

First you should config it.

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
  GeolocationBG.config({
    url: 'https://localhost:3000/api/geolocation',
    debug: false //or true if you want to see logs
  });

 //here we are starting the service each 1 minute
  Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
   GeolocationBG.start();
   Session.set('geoStart',true); //Trigger a Session when the service start
  }, 60000);

  //This is how we stop the service.
  Tracker.autorun(function(){
    if (Session.get('geoStart')){
     GeolocationBG.stop();
     Session.set('geoStart',false);
    }
  })
}
```

Here you have the **that reads the device's geolocation every minute** behavior.

Now the  **and inserts it into a Mongo collection** step.

First Create a collection.

```
//Global collection put it on a lib folder or a very top if(Meteor.isServer/Client)

GeoLog = new Mongo.Collection('GeoLog');
```

Now on the `server` do the following (if you remove the autopublish package).

```
Meteor.publish('geoData',function(){
  return GeoLog.find();
})
```

Now on the client side(the insert part and subscribe)

```
//You can place the subscript into the lib folder inside a if(Meteor.isClient);
//or inside a Meteor.startup.

Meteor.startup(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('geoData')
})



 //Did you remember the Meteor.setTimeout? on the if(Meteor.isCordova)?, lets update it.

Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
   GeolocationBG.start();
   GeolocationFG.get(function(location) {
                 GeoLog.insert({
                  location: location,
                  uuid: GeolocationBG.uuid(),
                  device: GeolocationBG.device(),
                  //userId: Meteor.userId(), optional
                  created: new Date()
                });
            });
   Session.set('geoStart',true); //Trigger a Session when the service start
  }, 60000);
```

You can use the `GeolocationFG.get(function(location) {});` inside an event handler, lets say a `button`.

**NOTE:** this is just an idea, im using only `if(Meteor.isCordova)` because you say **very simple iphone app**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Question: What exactly is the url attribute in the config object? I set it to my local server, but I get the following client error (I ruled out the possibility of my app not being connected to the server by inserting a dummy object into the db):

ERROR: HTTP.call() callback error.

Comment: check the [docs](https://github.com/zeroasterisk/meteor-cordova-geolocation-background) thas where you point the logs, in this case you should overwrite this to your location server, for example if you deploy into puegge it should look like  `url: 'https://pueggel.meteor.com/api/geolocation',`

Comment: I deployed the app to gpsapp.meteor.com and changed the url field. Now I get this: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/api/geolocation?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://gpsapp.meteor.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @Pueggel hmm well i don't really know why are you getting this error, it will be great if you create an issue on the Github repo, but let me do a little research about why are you getting this error.